# Реализация модулей без сборщиков

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь разобраться с модулями и в действующий момент, имея под крылом webpack сконструировать это всё довольно просто и весь импорт - экспорт описывается так же без проблем.

Но возник момент небольшого непонимания. Каким образом это раньше реализовывалось на чистом js без всяких сборщиков? То есть, есть условные 2 файла, 2 модуля, каждый из которых является самовызывающейся функцией, которая привязана к определённой переменной.

Их взаимодействие раньше можно было обеспечить только подключая к html файлу каждый из этих модулей?

Понимаю что вопрос звучит вероятно глупо и не особо актуально, но тем не менее меня он в покое не оставляет.

Comment: Были и другие сборщики, да и код писался по другому. Простейший сборщик: `cat *.js > dist/bundle.js` :)

Comment: Например [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/)